# Block Website in https

Tags: c#, https

This code block the website ex: http://google.com or plus.google.com but https://google.com doesn't work

```
e.Cancel = e.Url.Host.Contains("google");
```

Comment: We need more code than this. What event handler is this called in?

Comment: private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = e.Url.Host.Contains("google");
           
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
 { 
    e.Cancel = e.Url.ToString().Contains("google"); 
 }
```

Comment: read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs.url.aspx